# How to open default Scientific Calculator in android using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open scientific calculator of android device using intent for this I try

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
        if (pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")) {
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
                items.add(map);
            }
        }

        if (items.size() >= 1) {
            String packageName = (String) items.get(0).get("packageName");
            Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if (i != null)
                startActivity(i);
        } else {
            // Application not found
        }
```

But this open default calculator and I have to open scientific calculator

Comment: Do you try to print out `items` to see all the items? May be there is two packages' name contains "calcul" and `items.get(0)` get the default calculator instead.

Comment: I tried to print it.It prints only one package name

Comment: It is probably the Scientific Calculator's package name do not contain "calcul". You should find the what is the exact package name instead.

Comment: scientific calculator is open from menu of default calculator .

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find if there are any APIs for the default calculator. If it does not have any APIs documented, you can try reverse engineering the apk and find the package name and activity name.

Then you can use the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Replace with porper package name and activity name
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.CalActivity")); 
startActivity(intent);
```